# Add runtime environment variables in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build an application in C++ using the SDL library but unfortunately, it only works if the environment variable `DISPLAY` is set. It's quite easy to do, just running with `DISPLAY=:0.0 ./myapp` on the command line.

However, I'm trying to use the debugger from the CMake extension on VSCode to do so, but it doesn't work. I tried to add the following to the VSCode config, but it makes no difference.

```json
"cmake.testEnvironment": {
    "DISPLAY": ":0.0"
}
```

I also tried to add this to `CMakeLists.txt`, but also nothing happened:

```
set(ENV{DISPLAY} :0.0)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Editing CMakeLists.txt wouldn't help there. The question boils down to your editor, VSCode.

Comment: I highly doubt the solution to this involves anything to do with `CMake` since it's not involved in the running of your application.

Comment: I removed the Cmake tag and edited the title.

Comment: You probably need to edit `launch.json` and add the environment variable there: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_environment)

Comment: @drescherjm but I haven't `launch.json`. I'm using the debugger from the [CMake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) extension. I tried to create a launch.json, but I don't know how to execute it.

Comment: The documentation for CMake tools seems to indicate that you can change some settings to use a `launch.json`: [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md)